# Why is my while loop stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, while-loop, colors

I try to avoid while loops as best I can, I struggle to avoid infinite loops

I have a while loop that is designed to increment a colours lightness by 0.05 each loop until a value is reached. I believe have the function almost there but i have been fighting this for a while.

When the either the lightness value is 100 or more or the ratio condition is reached or surpassed, the loop should loop.

```
   let minLighterColor = Color(forGroundColor).hsl();

                while (minLighterColor.color[2] < 100 || Color(minLighterColor).contrast(Color(theme.palette.background.paper)) < 7) {
                    if (Color(minLighterColor).contrast(Color(theme.palette.background.paper)) < 7) {
                        Color(minLighterColor).lighten(0.05)
                    } else {
                        return minLighterColor;
                    }
                }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are using an OR-operator. Meaning that even if minLighterColor is greater than 100, your second check might still be true

Comment: What I want is for the second argument in the while to be false. i want the contrast to be higher than 7. I'm trying to achieve that by incrementing gradually the lightness of the colour so that we get as close to the original colour as possible.

Comment: let minLighterColor = Color(forGroundColor).hsl();

                    while `(Color(minLighterColor).contrast(Color(theme.palette.background.paper)) < 7) {
                            Color(minLighterColor).lighten(0.05)
             
                    }`

That is closer to the idea I am trying to get across.

Comment: I still get an infinite loop